# Parallels Plesk 12 on CentOS 6 not sending mail

Tags: google-cloud-platform, plesk, mail-server

I have installed Plesk 12 on CentOS 6. The server is on Google Cloud Compute Engine. All ports from 1 to 65000 are open in the firewall.

Whenever a PHP script on the site tries to send an e-mail, it doesn't arrive. In Plesk Mail Queue the message is marked as deferred. When I check the queue in terminal, the error is the connection to the mail server of the recipient has timed out.

I'm using Postfix, Dovecot, and PHP 5.6.20.

How to make it work?

Comment: Check telnet to any SMTP host on port 25 like: telnet smtp.somehost.tld 25

Comment: The port is listening. Can you please tell me what is the config file of SMTP and how the hosts should be written there?

Comment: I'm talking not about your server port but about outgoing connections to other servers on 25 port are even possible.

Comment: For example: `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 25` or `telnet ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 25`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this document https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

`Note: Port 25 is always blocked and cannot be used, even through the options described in this document.`

So I think it's better to setup SendGrid integration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify port 25 is listing on your server with the following command.

```
netstat -ntap | grep 25
```

and check your mail server IP reputation with the senderbase and mxtoolbox site. Might be your IP is blacklisted in spam databases and due to that you are facing this mail issues.

Comment: The port is listening, the reputation is neutral.